# which is considered as Basic SQL

Tags: discussion

which is considered as ***Basic SQL*** :

I have read the help of the site mainly this:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

and it is not clear to me: can they exemplify?

for example I want to ask a question about a query that I really consider to be basic, but I am almost sure that the solution is using joins;

*Then:*

the use of joins at what level is considered for the community of database experts?
And if it can be optimized by an advanced function, can it be considered a good question to be published on the site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please don't hesitate to post your question, taking into account [other guidelines](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977). The worst that can happen is that it'll be soon closed as "too localised" or "off-topic"; this will be the signal that the crowd here finds it too basic.

You can then take your, already well-prepared, question to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).