# Where should I post my question? DBA, Software Engineering or Code Review?

Tags: discussion

I want to ask about the structure of my database but I'm not sure where should I ask. Code review has the SQL tag about schemes and Software Engineering has the SQL about desing, but Database SE also sounds about "databases" althogh it is only for advanced questions, isn't it?. So, here I'm.

Basically I have a MS Access database, but now I want to improve our family shop database and upload it into a MySQL server that we already have but not use, and maybe combine some part of it with our website

Since I won't be using Access anymore I was planning to make a complete rework in my program and database to improve it.

So, I wanted to ask if the columns of my products table were fine or I should make them different (e.g: split the columns in two tables or do another thing).

So, can I ask about the table's columns design in DBA.SE or not?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Database Design is on-topic here.  Try to keep your question as specific as possible, and if you can, add [code to show what design you're contemplating](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example).