# how to show data as in a grid for adding in posts?

Tags: discussion, formatting

Often times I need to represent data in a way similar to [this one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/236639/22336):

...which is:

```
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| IfInOctets       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| IfOutOctets      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| inDiff           | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| outDiff          | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| time             | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| timeDiff         | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| inDiffFormatted  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| outDiffFormatted | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

What tool have them used to produce that formatted output?

In case this ends up as opinion based then just let me know how to look for such tools please.

It has to be easy to use from SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find some online tools for this purpose, but I think you should take a look at that [Max Vernon](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10832/max-vernon)'s question:

[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example)

Quoted from the question:

> Include test output, in text formatted as a table, to show both what
>   you're currently getting as well as what your desired output should
>   be. Search for "ascii table generator" on your [favorite search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ascii%20table%20generator)
>   - there are several that are extremely easy to use.